# Can I add my own panel to the widget page in wordpress using a plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, sidebar

Is it possible to develop a plugin that is able to add a panel to the widgets page? And could someone point me to a few articles to get me started if there is? I need to achieve something similar to the [customisable sidebar plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-sidebars/) where a panel was added via activation of the plugin.

Thanks

Comment: You mean sidebar area ? Your plugin can register sidebar and it will appear there https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar

Comment: Hi @Mohsin , not quite, I want a panel that could have sidebars added to it in the same way that a sidebar has widgets added to it. I've been looking all over for this however have only found so far articles similar to the one that you have mentioned.

Comment: Got it. I have not worked on that before, so maybe someone who has worked on that answer soon. By the way the plugin you referred, you can download that, look into files and see how they are implementing it as it is open source and all code is there for you to learn from:)